# What are the rules regarding chaining of "==" and "!=" in Python

Tags: python

This morning, I find myself writing something like:

```
if (a == b == c):
  # do something
```

And was surprised that it gave me the expected result.

I thought it would behave as:

```
if ((a == b) == c):
  # do something
```

But it obviously didn't. It seems Python is treating the first statement differently from the second, which is nice but I couldn't find any documentation or explanation regarding this.

I tested and got this:

```
In [1]: 2 == 2 == 2
Out[1]: True

In [2]: (2 == 2) == 2
Out[2]: False
```

Would someone care to explain me what are the rules regarding such "chaining" of `==` (or `!=`) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once. @ http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Neat, eh? You can also do `a < b < c` and such.

Comment: Not that I care much, but may the downvoter explain why he downvoted ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works with all comparison operators - eg, you can also do:

```
>>> 4 < 5 < 6
True
>>> 4 < 5 !=2
True
```

In general, [according to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in), `a op1 b op2 c` where `op1` and `op2` are any of: `<`, `>`, `!=`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`, `is` , `is not`, `in` or `not in` will give the same result as:

```
a op1 b and b op2 c
```

The docs also say that this can work with arbitrarily many comparisons, so:

```
>>> 5 != '5' != 'five' != (3+2)
True
```

Which can be a slightly confusing result sometimes since it seems to say `5 != (3+2)` - each operand is only compared with the ones immediately adjacent to it, rather than doing all possible combinations (which mightn't be clear from examples using only `==`, since it won't affect the answer if everything defines `__eq__` sanely).

Comment: Also works for `in` and `not in`, e.g. `4 in [4] in [[4]]` (not that I'm recommending this usage...)

Comment: @interjay indeed and I was actually editing those into my answer when your comment appeared. GMTA. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. My love for this language grows day after day ! ;)

Comment: @interjay However, the next logical extension, `4 and 5 in [4, 5]`, does not work as expected.  That's a false positive, as shown here:  `6 and 5 in [4, 5]` == True.

Comment: The lack of examples using chained `!=` is probably *because* it's a strange thing to do with a non-transitive operator.  If you really do want `a != b != c != d` to perform all possible checks, write something like `if len({a, b, c, d}) == 4:`.

Comment: Izkata, the example you wrote aren't good. 4 is valided to True and 6 is valided to True too. 5 is in the list so it is like True and True. Python doesn't support syntax like (4 and 5) in [4, 6]. But I admit it would be cool

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I think that was Izkata's point - `4 and 5 in [4, 5]` -> `True` can appear to be an extension of operator chaining, but isn't.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know the example you point out isn't chaining.

`2 == 2 == 2` is like  `(2 == 2) and ( 2 == 2)` which turns out to be `True and True`

while

`(2 == 2) == 2` is like `(True) == 2`

Answer (score 3):

Check here: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in